# ajax php parameter empty

Tags: php, ajax

I am passing this URL

```
"url=http://localhost.com/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=DeviceStatus&d=C5"
```

into this php file

```
<?php
//set POST variables
$url = $_POST['url'];
unset($_POST['url']);

$fields_string = "";
//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

For some reason it says unknown function f, but when I paste it into a browser manually it works perfectly fine??

Comment: do you have curl enable in your php ini?

Comment: I don’t see a function `f` nor call to `f`. Is that the complete code?

Comment: I guess the `count($_POST)` is wrong - `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($_POST));`. Previously you unsed POST[url], and there may be other stuff in `$_POST`. Probably you wanted to count `$fields_string`?

Comment: You set `$url` and unset `$_POST['url']`, but then work on with `$_POST`. You probably want to work with $url instead!?

Comment: f is a parameter in the url string.  I have copied the code from a tutorial for using php to make a Ajax call across doamins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you you try `urlencode`?

```
<?php
  //set POST variables
  $url = $_POST['url'];
  unset($_POST['url']);
  $fields_string = "";
  //url-ify the data for the POST
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
   $fields_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
   }
   rtrim($fields_string,'&');
   //open connection
   $ch = curl_init();
   //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
   //execute post
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   //close connection
   curl_close($ch);
   ?>
```

You can try it this way.

```
 <?php
  //set POST variables
  $url = $_POST['url'];

  unset($_POST['url']);

  $fields_string = "";
  //url-ify the data for the POST

  $ fields_string = http_build_query ($_POST);
   //open connection
   $ch = curl_init();
   //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);

   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
   //execute post
   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   //close connection
   curl_close($ch);
   ?>
```

Comment: urlencode returns the same "F unknown function" but when I copy the url into a browser it works!

Comment: I think this line `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($_POST));` is being used incorrectly. It should be set to true. See my updated answer.

Comment: Something is wrong there I manually put the url in and remed the CURLOPT_POST And POSTFIELDS and it worked ok.

Comment: When it loops through the t=ab is in url and missing from fields string, how do I remove from the URL and get it to go into the $fields_string??

Comment: Actually for my purposes it doesn't matter I can pass the URL whole and it works, I am happy with that!! thanks

Comment: my mistake I hadn't unremmed the hard code url so do need to build the parameters

Comment: Try it the other way I posted. I'm on my phone so formatting sucks

Comment: I have put the URL back together so its the same as what was originally passed and that works